# Instantiating View Controllers from Appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, appdelegate

If a Push Notification comes in and the user taps it, I load a specific view controller via this code:

```
let tabbarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("employerTabBarViewController") as! UITabBarController
tabbarController.selectedIndex = 0

self.window?.rootViewController = tabbarController
let navigationController = tabbarController.viewControllers?.first as!     UINavigationController
var applicantsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ApplicantsViewController") as! ApplicantsViewController
applicantsVC.job = job

navigationController.pushViewController(applicantsVC, animated: false)
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

My question is: Does this code instantiate ViewControllers over and over again for each tapped notification message so that the memory of the smartphone gets more and more used? And if that's the case, can I get rid of all the ViewControllers that have already been initialized by prior usages of the app before initializing new ones? Does `popToRootViewController` help?

** UPDATE **
I tried both of your recommendations, but memory usage increased by about 10 MB every time I tap the notification message. Maybe it's not correlated with the method I initialize the ViewControllers in the AppDelegate but the way I load the "ApplicantsViewController" or does initializing the Storyboard with `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)` cause this effect?

Here is the initializing of the ApplicantsViewController (I also uncommented `reloadData()` and `var tableViewController = UITableViewController()` - this didn't stop the memory increase):

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var openPositionsStatus: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var changeJobOfferStatusButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var job : JobOffer?
var favorites = [Employee]()
var applicants = [Employee]()
var applications = [Application]()
var takenPositions = 0
var refreshControl : UIRefreshControl?
var offeredJobsVC : OfferedJobsViewController?

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "receiveNotification:", name: "refreshApplicants", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "receiveNotification:", name: "jobOfferStatusChanged", object: nil)
}


deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    Helper.setBackground(self)

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: Selector("reloadData"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.updateJobOfferActionButton(self, jobOffer: self.job!, button: self.changeJobOfferStatusButton)


    var tableViewController = UITableViewController()
    tableViewController.tableView = self.tableView
    tableViewController.refreshControl = refreshControl
    // call reloadData after refreshControl solved sorting problems
    reloadData()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it will cause more and more ViewController stacked in the Navigation Controller. My option is to create a global variable in the appDelegate

```
var applicantsVC:ApplicantsViewController?
```

and in the function for notification comes in, do something like this:

```
if (applicantsVC == nil){
     self.applicantsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ApplicantsViewController") as! ApplicantsViewController
}
```

Comment: `yes, it will cause more and more ViewController stacked in the Navigation Controller` - it's not true, because `tabbarController` will be reallocated on every push notification.

Comment: I tried your method and updated my question. thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't allocate more memory on every push notification, you reallocate that memory.

Every time you create new instance of `UITabBarController` and put it as `rootViewController` for `UIWindow` instance:

```
let tabbarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("employerTabBarViewController") as! UITabBarController  
self.window?.rootViewController = tabbarController
```

It means that every time you deallocate current `tabBarController` with full stake of view controllers, and allocate new one. You are good with this way.

Comment: I tried your method and updated my question. thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Sierra101 how did you measure memory usage?

Comment: @Sierra101 if you use instruments be sure that you check `# Persistent` and `Persistent bytes` columns, but not `Total bytes`.

Comment: It seems that my problem is not related on how I instantiate the ViewControllers from appdelegate. That's why I opened a new question concerning this memory leak right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726954/massive-memory-consumption-imageio-jpeg-data 
Thanks for your help so far!