# Massive Memory Consumption: ImageIO_jpeg_Data

Tags: ios, swift, memory, parse-platform, memory-leaks

I've got a TableViewController that shows an user image and some text per row entry. This image is loaded in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : ApplicantsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! ApplicantsCell

    {...}

    let image = UIImage(named: "avatar")
    cell.applicantImage.image = image

    if let applImage = applicant.image as PFFile? {
        applImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.applicantImage.image = image
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Every time I re-open the app and go to this TableViewController, Instruments shows me, that a new "ImageIO_jpeg_Data" object is created and the old ones get never released. Each of this objects takes about 13 MBs of memory... So after a few iterations, the memory usage passes 100 MB and goes on...:
[Memory Usage http://twail.net/stack/screen.png](http://twail.net/stack/screen.png).

And triggering a low memory warning in the simulator does not free any memory...

Can somebody help me how I can deallocate memory?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing two things wrong.

First, always scale the image down to the actual display size before adding it to the cell. Keeping a 13 MB image in memory just so you can show a tiny thumbnail version of that image in a cell is just wrong.

Second, this code makes no sense and will get you in trouble:

```
        if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            cell.applicantImage.image = image
        }
```

Remember, the cells are reused, so by the time this code runs, the cell pointed to by `cell` may no longer exist in the interface, or may be showing a different row of the table (because it was reused). Instead, store the (scaled-down) image in the data model and reload the table.

Comment: all images are prescaled the time they are stored to the db and consume about 20kbs each. they also get scaled using one of the UIViewContentMode options in IB. I found out that one of the main problem is setting the background image for each viewcontroller via `var mainBgImageView = UIImageView(image: Constants.mainBgImage)
        VC.view.addSubview(mainBgImageView)
        VC.view.sendSubviewToBack(mainBgImageView)
    }` in viewDidLoad. The background images file size is 26kb, but every time I reopen the app, 13 MB from ImageIO are allocated anew. in every new appearing VC.